# What is the difference between vector<vector<int> > v and vector <int>* v in memory allocation？

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management

I use these two types of two-dimensional vector to load a graph.

In the first case I use  `vector<vector<int> > v` to load the graph adjacency matrix, and in the second case I use `vector <int>* v`to do so, when I initialize it with `vector <int>* v = new vector <int>[n]`.(n is the number of vetices).

It appeared on the official judge platform that `vector<vector<int> > v` takes memory of over 5000kb, while `vector <int>* v`takes only about 3600kb. What's the difference between these two types of two-dimensional vector?

I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: How big is `n`? How do you populate those vectors?

Comment: a vector needs a little bit of extra because it can do more than an array, but I would not expect it to be that much. Can you show the code?

Comment: I populate the vectors like this:
 
    ```vector<int>* graph = new vector<int>[n];```    
 
    ```int source = 0, dest = 0;```    
 
    ```//building undirected graph```    
 
    ```while (cin >> source && cin >> dest) ```
    ```{graph[source].push_back(dest);  graph[dest].push_back(source);}```

Comment: n is a natural number under 100000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<vector<int> > v(n)` is a single `vector` internally holding a pointer to an array of `n` `vector<int>` elements.

`vector <int>* v = new vector <int>[n]` is a pointer to an array of `n` `vector<int>` elements.

In that regard, they are virtually identical, just that the 1st one manages the array for you and will free it automatically when appropriate, whereas you have to manage the 2nd one yourself.

However, in terms of memory usage, the technical difference between the two approaches is that a `vector` has to internally keep track of metadata related to its `size()` and `capacity()` methods, so there is slightly more memory overhead between using `vector v` vs `vector* v`, but that overhead is only a few mere bytes.  However, the fact that a `vector` has separate `size()` and `capacity()` means that the `vector` may allocate room for *more* elements than are actually valid in the array.  So, even though you are adding `n` `vector<int>` elements to `vector v`'s internal array, `v` may allocate room for `m` elements, where `m > n`.

Whenever you push elements into a `vector`, if its new `size()` would exceed its current `capacity()`, the internal array has to be reallocated to grow larger, and most implementations will grow that array by 1.5x-2x for efficiency, to avoid having to reallocate the array on every push.

That could easily account for the extra memory usage you are seeing, depending on *how* you are populating `vector v`.